# why can't find/parse this element in HTML?

Tags: html

Hi I'm practicing extracting information from a website.

(I'm using `python`, `selenium`, and `beautifulsoup`, which doesn't matter too much. The question is about finding an element in HTML.)

So (1) I want info in the table in graph. I located the table using `Firefox Inspector`: `<table id='......'>`
[image]

(2) but in my code I can't find it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/corpweb/UCCSearch/UCCSearch.aspx'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# navigate to the page I want using selenium
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_rdoSearchO").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_txtName").send_keys("mcdonald")
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_cboOState")).select_by_visible_text("Massachusetts")
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_UCCSearchMethodO")).select_by_visible_text("Begins With")
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_btnSearch").click()
# now on next page, click link (selenium)
link_text = '95352026'
driver.find_element_by_link_text(link_text).click()

### real question starts here:
# now on the page I want

# in firefox inspector find: <table id="MainContent_tblFilingHistory">
table_id = 'MainContent_tblFilingHistory'

# try find it
table = driver.find_elements_by_id(table_id)
len(table) # length = 0, can't find it


html.find(table_id) # -1, HTML really doesn't have this string
```

Comment: Do you have a frame in you page ?

Comment: thanks @florentbr  what does frame mean? - sorry i don't know too much about internet. The code is complete. If you want to take a look, you can run it and check the id of that table. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you have trouble to locate is in another window. You need to tell the driver to switch the context to that window:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/corpweb/UCCSearch/UCCSearch.aspx')
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_rdoSearchO").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_txtName").send_keys("mcdonald")
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_cboOState")).select_by_visible_text("Massachusetts")
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_UCCSearchMethodO")).select_by_visible_text("Begins With")
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_btnSearch").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('95352026').click()

#switch to the next window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

table = driver.find_elements_by_id('MainContent_tblFilingHistory')
```